# git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey) . But ssh git@github.com works

Tags: git, github, ssh

Using GIT and SSH on Windows. RSA Private key is loaded to the ssh-agent. SSH-agent is running.

```
ssh-add -l    # lists my private key successfully
```

SSH to any of my Linux machines work nicely.

```
ssh username@AnyOfMyRemoteLinuxmachines           # I get a successful passwordless access
```

SSH to the git@github.com authenticates okay.
ssh git@github.com

```
PS > ssh git@github.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi user! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

GIT clone refusing access to a pubic git repository: For example:

```
PS G:\My Drive\Projekti\2022\Ansible> git clone org-23183426@github.com:smallstep/crypto.git
Cloning into 'crypto'...
org-23183426@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**However, if I copy my unencrypted `id_rsa` file to the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` directory, git works okay**

- It's not a key problem, because I can authenticate to my Linux machines and Github successfully both with using the agent as well as the unencrypte `id_rsa` file.
- It's not the agent problem, because the agent loads the key correctly, it works with SSH my linux machines.

Any other ideas?

Comment: There is difference between `ssh **git**@github.com` and `git clone **org-23183426**@github.com:smallstep/crypto.git`

Comment: to add to phd's comment : when interacting with github you should always use the `git` ssh account : `git clone git@github.com:...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question title says:

> ```
> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)
> ```

But your question says:

> ```
> org-23183426@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
> ```

You should consider trying to gain access as `git`, not as `org-23183426` (both `@github.com`).

Edit: it turns out that if you click around on GitHub at https://github.com/smallstep/crypto and ask them for a clone URL, the https URL is OK, but the ssh one is not.  "Why not" is a good question, but is one to ask GitHub support.  Don't use the one GitHub generate here.

Comment: I am merely copying repo from a public GIT repository on Github.
https://github.com/smallstep/crypto

Why would I need to edit this?

Comment: GitHub *require* you to attempt to log in as user `git`. Attempting to log in as some other user will always fail. Exercise: your name is (apparntly) KrNeki. What happens when you go to some official, state-controlled location and present ID that claims that you're Daffy Duck?

Comment: That I understand. The issue I have here is - this is a public repository. In order to get a local clone of it, you press the button the get the URL. With this particular specific repository, the URL gives me a user that is not GIT.  This was my problem, but I still don't know why GitHub would provide an URL on a public repository  that only works for 1 user.  Click on Code-->SSH and you will see that. To me, that is strange.

Comment: Public or not, you definitely still need the `git` part before `git@`. Why GitHub would give you a bogus string is a good question, but is one for GitHub support :-) (And, having poked around on GitHub, I see that it does indeed do that. I've never bothered with that button before.)